# Does Akka Remoting support one-way only connections?

Tags: android, networking, client-server, netty, akka

I have an Akka system running on an Android device, which talks to an Akka system on a server via Akka Remoting.

The Android device may get any IP address, the IP may change while the application runs, and the IP can be unreachable from the server. Thus I've configured Akka on the Android device with `akka.remote.netty.hostname = "0.0.0.0"` and `akka.remote.netty.port = 8000`.

The Android Akka system gets a reference to an actor on the server, sends messages to it, and the Actor on the server records the sender() actorRef and keeps sending messages back to it. This works when both the server and Android device are on the same wlan, and when they are talking via GPRS over the internet.

Now I'm taking a closer look on connection losses and reconnects. The scenario I've been focusing on is this:

- The Android device and server is both on a wlan.
- The Android device sends a message to the server.
- Akka remoting on Android produces `RemoteClientStarted`.
- Akka remoting on server produces `RemoteClientStarted` and `RemoteServerClientConnected`.
- Then I turn off the wlan on Android, wait a few seconds and turn it on again. No messages are attempted sent to the server in between.
- Akka remoting on Android produces `RemoteClientShutdown` and `RemoteClientError` (ETIMEDOUT)
- Akka remoting on server says nothing.
- Android sends a message to the server.
- Server produces `RemoteServerClientConnected` and receives the message.
- Server tries to send a message (call it **A** for questions below) to Android, and produces: `RemoteServerError`, `RemoteServerClientDisconnected`, `RemoteClientShutdown`, `RemoteServerClientClosed`.
- Android never gets the message from the server.
- Server tries to send another message, but Akkas `RemoteClient` says:

  - *[PassiveRemoteClient@akka://xxx@0.0.0.0:8000] has been shut down*
  - *Starting remote client connection to [akka://xxx@0.0.0.0:8000|/0.0.0.0]*
  - *RemoteClientError@akka://vts@0.0.0.0:8000: Error[...*

This last error seems to come from that Akka Remote wants to create a new `ActiveRemoteClient` instead of reusing the existing `PassiveRemoteClient`. I guess this again comes from that the server observes the RemoteServerClientConnected event before it sees the errors/disconnects/shutdowns/clientcloseds.

Now the questions:

1. **How can I make the server reuse the last incoming connection (`PassiveRemoteClient`) from the Android device when sending message A in this scenario?**
2. **How can I instruct the server to not ever try to connect back to the client?**

Versions:

- Android: 15 (4.0.3)
- Akka: 2.1
- Java: 1.6 64bits
- Scala: 2.10.1
- Netty: 3.5.8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might not really be the answer you have been hoping for, but here it goes (I’m the Akka tech lead).

Akka remoting is designed to work between systems which act as peers. The driver behind the development is to build the cluster support which started appearing in version 2.1 and which will be officially supported—and further developed—from 2.2 onwards. This has a few important consequences:

- `ActorRefs` shall be location transparent, meaning that they work the same no matter where you use them, and hence each node needs to be able to connect to the node where a given reference points to.
- Communication between Akka nodes is fundamentally symmetric even if your usage of it may not be.
- Passing around `ActorRef` as a means to conduct a conversation means that the entity pointed to via the reference needs to stay available or the communication will fail; and staying available means “at the same location pointed to by the reference”.

What this means for your scenario is that you will be better off coupling your actor systems not using plain remoting but instead using something else which supports the short-lived associations you suffer from. You could for example expose the server as a REST service, or you could just use bare TCP (or even UDP) using the Akka IO layer. In the actor handling the endpoint on the server side you can then recognize if the same client talks to you from a different network locations, buffer reply messages, masquerade that external actor behind a local proxy actor etc. With this scheme you can even build in reliable messaging over your unreliable channels (using ACKing) and the beauty is that within the server (possibly a cluster) all communication just works because the problematic part of how to talk to the client is encapsulated in one spot.

Long story short: your use-case is not one which is supported by plain Akka remoting out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for a thorough answer and especially suggestions on how to make it work. Quick follow up: `RemoteTransport` seems to be base for implementing ones own remoting underneath Akka. It's undocumented so I have to ask: is this the recommended way? Will the mechanism change drastically in upcoming versions of Akka?

Comment: RemoteTransport will change for 2.2 and while it is conceivable that special applications create their own we do not expect that to happen often. There are a lot of assumptions connected to actor messaging which might not match your needs.

Comment: Okay, guess I'll stay away from `RemoteTransport` then.

For the curious: I ended up testing akka-zeromq. It is built against zeromq-2.1 which was unacceptable for me. So I tested jeromq, which is supposed to be a pure-java port of zeromq3. Unfortunately this didn't work as a drop in replacement of the scala-zeromq-binding that comes with akka-zeromq, but I forked the akka-zeromq module and replace dependency on scala-zeromq-binding with jeromq instead.Worked as a charm, but testing on Android still remains.

Comment: I'm not on that list. But feel free to copy paste this: Don't have time to pack it as a standalone project and put it on github right now, but what I've done is this:
1. Replace all imports of org.zeromq... with org.jeromq... 2. Replaced _one_ instance of an int field access. Other than that the APIs where alike. I've not done much testing yet though, but I've initialized a jeromq-actor and processed messages, and it behaves as expected. Maybe you could create an akka-jeromq module for those less inclined to fiddle around with dlls?